# Find and Replace VBA/Macro in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, macros, vba

Another Excel VBA question. I'm using Excel 2010

I want to create a Macro that will remove the following 3 symbols in any cell for a selected range:

[  ]   "

**For example**; If I select a range of cells with the following in them:

[my name]

I want to remove the symbol/character leaving no space behind (nothing)

Using the find replace/substitute function works but it is taking too long.

Thanks

Comment: more details needed. which column? one column only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Removechar()

Selection.Replace What:=Chr(34), Replacement:=vbNullString, Lookat:=xlPart
Selection.Replace What:=Chr(91), Replacement:=vbNullString, Lookat:=xlPart
Selection.Replace What:=Chr(93), Replacement:=vbNullString, Lookat:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Using ASCII character codes.